# Cannot clear data in text editor (using jasny text editor)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask you a question about jQuery or javaScript code, I would like to clear all data in my text editor after success of responding result with PHP.

Here is HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <textarea name="textarea text-desc" class="jqte-test text-desc"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hre is a jQuery code :

```
$("#btn-for-text").on("click",function(){  
        var text_desc   = $(".text-desc").val();    
        $.ajax({
                url   : "php/respon_result.php",
                type  : "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data  : {text_data_desc : text_desc},
                success : function(data){        
                    if(data.result=='error'){
                        alert("Description is required!");
                    }else{
                        $result = "<div class='blog'>";
                        $result += "<textarea name='textarea' class='jqte-test hidden'>"+data.desc+"</textarea><div>"+data.desc+"</div>";
                        $result += "<p class='remove'>Remove</p>";
                        $result += "</div>";           

                            $(".whole_result").append($result);  
                            // clear text editor value
                            $(".text-desc").val('');
                        }, 2000 );

                    }

                },
                error  : function(data){
                    alert('Error log');
                }

            });
             // return false;
        });
```

You see I use below code to clear value in text editor but still not work :

```
$(".text-desc").val('');
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: What's the `}, 2000 );`  in your script? Is it a typo?

Comment: oh, sorry there is not that code .

Comment: Are you willing to show us correct code then? Also, I can't google *"jasny text editor"*, what's that?